It is possible to improve even more?
I have a big React app with 4205 Jest test running in a CI and it is taking more than 40 minutes to run all the tests. This amount of time is normal?
Versions:
NPM: 7.24.0
Node: 16.10.0
@testing-library/jest-dom: 6.4.2
@testing-library/react: 12.1.5
@testing-library/user-event: 14.5.2
jest: 29.7.0
jest-canvas-mock: 2.3.1
jest-environment-jsdom: 29.4.0
jest-junit: 16.0.0
jest-sonar: 0.2.16
jest-transform-stub: 2.0.0
jsdom: 21.1.0

jest.config.js:
module.exports = {
  clearMocks: true,
  restoreMocks: true,
  moduleNameMapper: {
    //some options
  },
  setupFiles: ["<rootDir>/buildTools/define-deprecated-global.js"],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/buildTools/setupTests.js"],
  transform: {
    //some options
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [`/node_modules/(?!${esModules})`],
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ["/test.js"],
  testTimeout: 250000,
  coverageDirectory: "target/coverage",
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageReporters: ["json", "lcov", "clover"],
  reporters: [
    //some entries
  ]
};

package.json script:
"test:ci": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/.bin/jest --maxWorkers=20% --watchAll=false --silent",

Recently I tried to change package.json to this but the time increased:
"test:ci": "node --optimize-for-size --max-old-space-size=8192 --gc_interval=100 --concurrent-recompilation --no-compilation-cache --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/.bin/jest --maxWorkers=50% --watchAll=false --silent --ci",

Are there any recommendations to improve this? Any better configuration? Any better alternatives to Jest?
I know that Node 20 has a fix for a memory leak, but I've already tried with Node 20, and the testing time is still huge.

Maybe your tests are not optimal?

What are the tests testing? And how? Testing basic JS should be blazing fast. But trying to test, say, a component that needs to be in a browser (e.g., through Karma or something) is going to be much slower. But if you're running your pure JS tests in a browser, then that's going to be slower than just in Node. And if you're re-running the browser for every test, that's going to be even slower.

Tests could also be slow because of lack of mocking. For example, importing an entire module when you could just mock the output of one function you need from that module.

Possible help:
no-compilation-cache
I followed this suggestion
https://dev.to/retyui/resolve-memory-leaks-caused-by-jest-with-nodejs-16x-and-18x-javascript-heap-out-of-memory-3md5 and just added --no-compilation-cache to package.json but I don't see any improvement.
Static maxWorkers
I found --maxWorkers doesn't work very well in a CI environment. I'm requesting 9000m (9 cores) of CPU to the CI build. And with --maxWorkers=20% sometimes the tests run with 9 cores, sometimes with 6, sometimes with 4. So, if I'm requesting 9000m, probably is better to use --maxWorkers=9 or --maxWorkers=7.
Coverage
I read somewhere that gathering test coverage during test execution can increase test execution time. So I'm thinking about moving test coverage gathering to a different stage of CI.
To do that, I believe, in the package.json I need to add another command and call it in the new CI stage: "test:coverage": "jest --coverage".
And in my jest.config.js, I need to disable coverage gathering during tests execution: collectCoverage: false.
Promises
I have always extra care with promises because I know they can exponentially increase my tests time and they can cause multiple flaky tests.
So I:

always try to use async-await instead of .then();
ensure the promise is always returned when I use .then();
always await for promises result. If I'm not sure if a function will return a promise or not, I check what kind of result it will return, and if is a promise, so I obviously need to await for it;
never use async or / and await if not necessary. I've noticed that if any async or / and await are used incorrectly in the code, it will cause some flakyness in the tests.

To prevent some of those cases, I added these rules in my .eslintrc.json:
"require-await": "error",
"no-return-await": "error",

Another suggestion is to use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-promise
A thing I'm wandering is if doing this can increase memory leaks (because I have many tests like this):
functionToBeTested() {
  requestSomeThingToTheServer(123).then(apiResult => {
    doSomething(apiResult);
    doSomethingMore();
  });
}

test("check the Server request", (done) => {
  
  mockServerRequest((requestParams) => { //is mocking requestSomeThingToTheServer() action
    expect(requestParams).toEqual(123);
    done();
  });
  
  functionToBeTested();
});

According with this link https://betterprogramming.pub/the-4-types-of-memory-leaks-in-node-js-and-how-to-avoid-them-part-2-f21fbda5c33b:

Promises get stored in memory and they do not clear until they are
either handled or rejected

So if I use done() in the test during the promise execution, it memory will not clear and can be a problem?
Vitest
I'm strongly considering migrating to Vitest. People say it's faster than Jest and doesn't seem difficult to migrate:

https://medium.com/wiiisdom-labs/how-to-migrate-from-jest-to-vitest-without-headaches-ee200510738e
https://vitest.dev/guide/migration#migrating-from-jest

React 18
I'm not using React 18 yet but I'm concern because of this: https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/1235
Seems the tests time will increase even more with React 18.
Some extra info
https://apidog.com/blog/jest-test-running-concurrently/
https://snird.medium.com/do-not-use-node-js-optimization-flags-blindly-3cc8dfdf76fd
https://gist.github.com/stormwild/4bd3c1ec50ed055a363012a403b16365
https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-promise
